# html body tag limitations in chrome and 'I.E'

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

to boost up the performance of the web site i put all the contents from the db ( not very big ) to body data tag. i.e.

```
<body data-blog="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode($blog) ); ?>">
```

The site worked ok on localhost and i updated it to the live server.

When i access the data from this site it is working fine no problem here. The problem comes when some one else accesses the site. I tested it using firefox 4. on my computer it works but it does not work on any other computer. It does show the data in the body tag but the simple javascript fails to display content without giving any error.

I do not know how can i debug this and what could be the potential problem with it. below is the code i am using to display the data out of the body tag.

```
<body data-blog="<?php echo htmlspecialchars( json_encode($blog) ); ?>">
        <script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#h_menu li").click(function(e)
    {

         var cid = $(this).attr('id');
         $("#contents").empty();
          var blog = $(document.body).data('blog');
            var tags = $.parseJSON(blog);


            $("#tmenu").empty();


                for(var n in tags)
                {
                    if( tags[n].cat_id == cid )
                        $('#tmenu').append("<li id='"+tags[n].id+"'>"+ tags[n].tag_name +"</li>");
                }
    });
    $("#tmenu li").live("click",function()
    {
        var id =  $(this).attr('id')  ;
        var blog = $(document.body).data('blog');
        var tags = $.parseJSON(blog);
        $('#contents').empty().hide();
        $('#contents').html(tags[id-1].tag_content).fadeIn(600);
    });
});
</script>
```

I forgot to mention it only works in FF4, chrome and I.E doesn't show data even on my computer from localhost so i am sure i must be doing some thing WRONG. but which thing i dont know and why is it working even from live site in my firefox ?

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this is better for performance than having the content in a hidden div.  Seems the encoding and decoding and element creation would eat up any CPU cycles you saved.

Comment: if i have contents in a hidden div then still i would use the javascript to fetch out the desired data by sending him the id so it will take the same time for putting data into hidden div and in body tag.

Comment: @G molvi:  You said it: "it will take the same time".  Add to that the cost of creating DOM elements on the fly vs the cost of letting the HTML parser do that at page load.  So where's the performance gain?

Comment: Congratulations, you just made your site inaccessible by anyone with js disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to stick that data in an hidden element somewhere instead of using the data. Also data is meant to be written and read using jQuery, I don't know if writing directly data-blog in the html will do the same without issues.